# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close' for reading one file

Tags: python

For opening and reading 1 file even after adding the close argument it is giving the error. The code written is as below:

```
infilename = "Rate.txt"
infile = open(infilename, "r").readlines()
firstLine = infile.pop(0) #removes the header(first line)
infile = infile[:-1]#removes the last line
for line in infile:
    a = line.split()
    CheckNumeric = a[4]
    CheckNumeric1 = a[5]
    strfield = a[3]
infile.close()
```

Comment: `.readlines()` makes `infile` into a `list`

Comment: ``infile`` is not a handler to the file, is a ``list`` generated by ``readlines`` method

Answer (score 3):

By doing `infile = open(infilename, "r").readlines()` you have actually assigned `infile` to be a `list`, rather than an open file object. The garbage collecter should sweep up your open file and close it for you, but a better way to handle this would be to use a [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) block:

```
infilename = "Rate.txt"
with open(infilename, "r") as infile:
    line_list = infile.readlines()

firstLine = line_list.pop(0) #removes the header(first line)
line_list = line_list[:-1]#removes the last line
for line in line_list:
    a = line.split()
    CheckNumeric = a[4]
    CheckNumeric1 = a[5]
    strfield = a[3]
```

In the code above, everything that is indented within the `with` block will execute while the file is open. Once the block ends the file is automatically closed.

Answer (score 1):

Value stored in the `infile` variable is not a file object, it is a list. Because your called `readlines` method.

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
infile = open(infilename, "r").readlines()
```

you have read the lines of the file and assign the list to `infile`. But you haven't assigne the file to a variable.

If you want to explicitly close the file:

```
someFile = open(infilename, "r")
infile = someFile.readlines()
...
someFile.close()
```

or use `with` which close the file automatically:

```
with open(infilename, "r") as someFile:
    infile = someFile.readlines()
    ....
print "the file here is closed"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
infile = open(infilename, "r")
# this resp. infile is a file object (where you can call the function close())

infile = open(infilename, "r").readlines()
# this resp. infile is a list object, because readlines() returns a list
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ffisegydd mentioned above, make use of **with statement** introduced in in Python 2.5. It will automatically close the file for you after the nested code block. And yet, in case an exception also happened the file will be closed before the exception is caught, pretty handy.

For more info, checkout this out on the context manager: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html
I actually make use of the context manager to achieve somewhat some level of maintainability.

Comment: You may also used my_list.pop()

Answer (score 1):

I would use this more memory efficient code:

```
infilename = "Rate.txt"
with open (infilename) as f:
   next(f) # Skip header
   dat = None
   for line in f:
        if dat: # Skip last line
            _, _, _, strfield, CheckNumeric,  CheckNumeric1 = dat.split()
        dat = line
```